# Rename duplicate record with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, redundancy, deduplication

I know you can select duplicate rows in MYSQL with the following query:

```
SELECT ID, bedrijfsnaam, plaats, COUNT( * ) 
FROM profiles
GROUP BY bedrijfsnaam, plaats
HAVING COUNT( * ) >1
```

I want to able to select the duplicates and rename them with PHP. Is that possible?
If it finds three duplicates for one 'bedrijfsnaam-plaats'-combination, I want to add
'I', 'II', 'III' at the end of the 'bedrijfsnaam' value. Is that even possible? Is there
some kind of loop I could run?

Thanks..

Comment: Yes. It's possible - although the rules for roman numerals are a little cumbersome

Comment: In software the answer to almost all 'is it possible' questions is 'yes'. This is no exception. The real question is 'how much does it cost?' Try something, post the code if you get stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these 2 query can be an answer:

```
create table maptable as 
SELECT
  p2.ID,
  concat(p2.bedrijfsnaam,count(*)) as bedrijfsnaam_new
FROM profiles p
JOIN profiles p2 on p2.bedrijfsnaam = p.bedrijfsnaam
 AND p2.plaats = p.plaats
 AND p2.ID > p.ID
group by p2.id,p2.bedrijfsnaam, p2.plaats;

update
  profiles,
  maptable
set
  profiles.bedrijfsnaam=bedrijfsnaam_new
where
  profiles.id=maptable.id;
```

The first part is based on Denis' answer...

Comment: I think OP wants roman numerals. :-P

Comment: :-)
For small numbers it is possible to use `repeat('I',count(*))` instead of the `count(*)`... But this gives correct roman number only under four...

Comment: Yeyeyeye. We can do that. :-)

Comment: (Btw, shoot me an email if you're in Budapest. I'm in Hungary too.)

Comment: That looks like it should do it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting, you can find the rows that are dups directly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p2.ID, p2.bedrijfsnaam, p2.plaats
FROM profiles p
JOIN profiles p2 on p2.bedrijfsnaam = p.bedrijfsnaam
 AND p2.plaats = p.plaats
 AND p2.ID > p.ID          -- this is where the magic occurs
```

Then run an update accordingly...

Comment: Perhaps, but this isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @MikeW: well, hopefully OP can take it from there and run an update...

Comment: Probably not, since the essence of his question was 'how do I perform an update?'

Comment: I see no reason to downvote, even though the answer was obvious, selecting them directly is the start of the solution indeed. Thanks Denis.

Comment: This query can give strange results for higher level multiplications... If there are 3 same record, the highest id's owner will be listed twice.